# Output (built files) from SBT in a separate directory

Tags: scala, sbt

For CI, I'd like to build the project fresh every time. However, `sbt compile` ends up littering `target` folders all throughout the checkout. `git clean -fxd` or similar can remove those files, but is there any way to have SBT just not put them there in the first place?

Is there a way to tell SBT to put compiled files into a separate directory structure, a la CMake?

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way:

```
target := file("/my/target")
```

However, SBT will still put files in `project/target`, and AFAIK there nothing you can do about that.

Though `git clean -fxd` isn't so bad either :) It's the best, most reliable way (no matter *what* your build tool does) to make a clean working tree.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could instruct sbt to place the output files somewhere else, you'd still need to clean this other directory in order to get a clean compile.

If you want to build your project 'fresh', why not use `sbt clean compile` ?

Adding the `target/` directory to `.gitignore` takes care of the 'littering' from a git perspective.

Comment: that'd be fine, because the output directory would be in a transient docker container.